# Eclipse RCP application - how to create a executable

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, installation, rcp

I've created an Eclipse Plugin clicking *New > Plug-in Development > Plug-in Project*.

In this project, I've modified the **plugin.xml** file and added new **Views** to create an example, and it works succesfully when I press Run button, loading a new Eclipse instance in which I can show my example perspective whit its views. It looks like this, with my additions marked:

[MyPerspectiveAndViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVyqc.png)

Now I want to create (I don't know what I need exactly) something to execute it without pressing the Run button, something like a Jar file.

I've been taking a look on Internet and I learned that Eclipse provides a tool call Oomph (also called Eclipse Intaller), and with Oomph I should create:

- **Product Setup Model**
- **Project Setup Model**

It seems like de Project Setup Model file can be added to an installation process. So I search for tutorials to do it, like https: / / eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/oomph-basic-tutorial/, getting the setup file, like this:

[MySetupFileCreated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ditHZ.png)

But when I create the project setup model, I don't know how to include my example project, so I can't show my perspective with my views.

Anyone knows how to create it in an Eclipse RCP application like this example?

Thanks :)

Comment: Note that if you just want an executable RCP without an installer you don't need to use Oomph (File > Export > Eclipse Product for example).